# How can I change an IBAction to mouseEntered?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, ibaction

I want to create an IBAction when my mouse enters an NSButton. Whenever I create an IBAction from the button, it only works when I click it.

How can I make it so that the IBActions works when my mouse enters the button?

Answer (score 1):

You can subclass your button cell and set its property `showsBorderOnlyWhileMouseInside` to `true`. Then you can simply override `mouseEntered` method:

```
import Cocoa

class ButtonCell: NSButtonCell {
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        showsBorderOnlyWhileMouseInside = true
    }
    override func mouseEntered(with event: NSEvent) {
        super.mouseEntered(with: event)
        print(#function)
    }
    override func mouseExited(with event: NSEvent) {
        super.mouseExited(with: event)
        print(#function)
    }
}
```

---

Another option if you don't want to set `showsBorderOnlyWhileMouseInside` to `true` is to subclass `NSButton` and add a tracking area to it. You will need to pass your `ButtonCell` as the owner:

```
import Cocoa

class Button: NSButton {
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        addTrackingArea(.init(rect: bounds, options: [.activeInKeyWindow, .mouseEnteredAndExited], owner: cell as! ButtonCell, userInfo: nil))
    }
}
```